# How to use cookie obtained in BrowserWindow within webview

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, webview, electron

I have searched all available information on this and the documentation is not helping me.

I have an Electron app (React internals) where a web page is to be shown in a [webview](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag).

The domain e.g. `https://root.domain.com` stays the same but the rest of the URL will be different depending on props passed to the component showing the webview.

I found some code [here](https://github.com/BuildingXwithJS/building-electron-apps-with-js/blob/master/src/api/youtube/index.js) linked from a Youtube video from [BuildingXwithJS](https://github.com/BuildingXwithJS) on testing which will use a BrowserWindow to allow a user login, then save the authenticated cookie for use within the app.

```
  auth() {

    const remote = electron.remote;
    // Get a partitioned session to use with webview
    const ses = remote.session.fromPartition("myPartition");

    // create new electron browser window
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    // cleanup on close
    win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null;
    });

    // wait for page to finish loading
    win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {

      // if auth was succesful
      if (win.webContents.getURL() === 'https://root.domain.com/Home/') {

        // get all cookies
        win.webContents.session.cookies.get({}, async (error, cookies) => {

          if (error) {
            console.error('Error getting cookies:', error);
            return;
          }

          // store cookies
          cookies.forEach(c => {

           if(c.domain.includes('root.domain.com')){

            ses.cookies.set(c,(e) => e? console.log("Failed: %s",e.message):null})

           }

          // close window
          win.close();
        });
      }
    });

    // Load login page
    win.loadURL(loginURL);

  }
```

Now when I view a page in webview in a separate component like this:

```
  <webview
    ref={a => (this.view = a)}
    partition="myPartition"
    src={`https://root.domain.com/${providedURL}`}
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%"
    }}
  />
```

I get the login page.

So I tried to following to set the cookies on the webview when it finishes loading, then reload:

```
  this.view.addEventListener("did-finish-load", e => {
    // Get partitioned session
    const ses = remote.session.fromPartition("myPartition");

    // Loop through cookies and add them to the webview
    ses.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {

      cookies.forEach(cookie => {

        // this.view doesn't return the webview in here so I use the event
        e.target.getWebContents().session.cookies.set(cookie,(e)=> e? console.log(e):null);

      });

       // Reload with cookies
       e.target.getWebContents().reload();
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false, failure: false });
  });
```

But still I get login page every time!

The frustrating thing about this is that the `auth()` function defined above (in another wrapper component) shows a logged in screen every time it runs after the user logs in once so the login session is active and the cookie is stored somewhere - but where? And how can I make this webview see it? Would I be better with an Iframe ?? My requirement to show an external url inline is a must have for my stakeholders so I need some way to make it work.

I am far from proficient in cookie management and the session management is not clear to me in Electron because there are a number of ways of accessing sessions `BrowserWindow.webContents().session` or`BrowserWindow.webContents().defaultSession` or
`import { session } from "electron"`.

Also, when I look at the application tab in devtools, these specific cookies are not showing anywhere (but others are). Why is this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? You did some great research here, thanks for sharing it with all. I'm trying to login, in a window/renderer, and use it in node-fetch in main.